# Jordan Canonical form with zero eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

Can anyone tell me how to find the Jordan Canonical form of the matrix below?

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2\\ 
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Obviously this matrix cannot be transformed into a diagonal. Since

$$ch_A=|(λ-AI)|=λ^3 \Rightarrow λ=0$$ with multiplicity of 3.

Can anyone help me find the Jordan canonical form of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix is obviously nilpotent, and in fact $\;A^3=0\,,\,\,A^2\neq0\;$ , and from here its JCF is

$$J_A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Or easier, as you began to argue: a nilpotent matrix is diagonalizable iff it is the zero matrix, so our matrix is non-diagonalizable...so now choose the size of the biggest Jordan block according to the *rank* of $\;A\;$ ...